# What is the usage of using generic type arguments as method parameters instead of using Object types?

Tags: java, generics

I am new to java and I have a little confusion in generics. One article used a method which prints all the elements of array and that method takes generic type argument. Different types of Primitive arrays had been passed to this method such as and it works well.

```
private <E> void printData(E[] arr) {
    for (E e : arr) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}`

Integer[] intArray = {1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 23};
Double[] doubleArray = {12.4, 34.5, 3.5, 45.67};
Character[] charArray = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};

printData(intArray);
printData(doubleArray);
printData(charArray);
```

My question is we can use Object[] type argument in  printData() mathod instead of E[] type. Because All the Types including primitive wrapper classes are inherited from Object. What is the the actual usage of using generic type argument within methods as parameters?  Are there any useful usages of using generic type arguments in methods?

What is the different between Object and Generic types can you please explain me with an example?

Can anybody help me please?

thanks a lot

Comment: In this example, there's no reason to use generics.

Comment: why didn't you read [Lesson: Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) before posting question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use generics for **type safety** and to **avoid casting**. Your example is not complete, let's take a look at this:

```
public class Printer<E> {

   public void printData(E[] arr) {
        for (E e : arr)
           System.out.println(e);
    }
}

Printer<Integer> intPrinter = new Printer<Integer>();
```

If you instantiate a new `Printer` object, you pass the generic type to the class. This means that this printer object will only work for this certain type. So you have a generic class (which you can instantiate for multiple types), but you will get type safety during compile time. If you try to pass a `String` to your `intPrinter` it won't work.

Comment: Agree... the OPs question is only part of the story and printing on it's own isn't a good example of the benefits of generics.